# Wp total cache and w3 super cache

Tags: wordpress

What plugin you choose for your wordpress project? I tried both and now I am using w3 super cache because I get more speed with it and it is important. Also, when I deleted my wp total cache before cache clear I get errors which I cant remove from my admin panel. Maybe someone know where is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the W3 Total Cache plugin from the Wp-content/plugins folder

Remove this line from `Wp-config` file – `(define(‘WP_CACHE’, true) )`

Delete `advanced-cache.php`, `dwp-total-cache-config.php`

Delete the entire w3tc folder from the Wp-content folder.

Check the `.htaccess` file; if you see any code added by W3 Total Cache, remove it.

I hope this will help you resolve your problem.

Comment: I do not see w3 total cache plugin in wp-content folder. No line in wp-config. advanced-cache.php and dwp-total-cache-config.php does not exist. No code in .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

@Paulius Jasiulis the message is pretty clear I think. Just go and delete the files

```
W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home/luxuriam/public_html/wp-content/db.php.

W3 Total Cache Error: some files appear to be missing or out of place. Please re-install plugin or remove /home/luxuriam/public_html/wp-content/object-cache.php.
```

Comment: I understand what message want to say but read again my post last lines:

"When I deleted this plugin there are no files like db.php or object-cache.php in wp-content folder. Also, I can't re-install it so what to do?"

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I suggest you reinstall the plugin once again and then follow these steps for uninstallation https://www.shoutmeloud.com/how-to-delete-uninstall-w3-total-cache-wordpress-plugin.html Do you have any other caching plugin installed?

Comment: Yes, I have another plugin installed "WP Super Cache"

Comment: Most likely that may be adding to the problem. I'd suggest to clear 'WP Super Cache' cache. deactivate it, reinstall 'W3 Total Cache' and follow the instructions for uninstalling it and the reactivate the WP Super Cache. Keep in mind that most of the time multiple cache plugins may cause conflicts.

Comment: Great! Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I cleared "WP Super Cache" plugin and deactivated it but still I can not reinstall "W3 Total Cache".